# understanding lotto program logic by skiena

Tags: algorithm

I am reading article from following location. Here is text snippet form document.

[Link](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/papers/lotto.doc)

> The problem of finding a minimum set of tickets that will guarantee a
>   win is not a trivial one. Given that P out of R outcomes will be from
>   the fortune-teller set, it is not difficult to see that there are NCP
>   = (N/P!)/(N-P)! possible P-subsets from the fortune-teller set that can occur in the winning ticket. If we were to pick all P-subsets from
>   the fortune-teller set W times and fill in the remaining R-P slots
>   arbitrarily, the set of tickets obtained will have at least W
>   occurrences of each P-subset and guarantee us W wins. However, such a
>   set need not be a minimal one and in most cases is not.
>
> We know from the fortune-teller’s promise that one of the P-subsets
>   will occur in the winning ticket. It is possible for two P-subsets to
>   differ by less than J numbers. When such a situation arises, the
>   subsets are said to overlap or cover one another with respect to the
>   shared J numbers and only one of the P-subsets must be in a purchased
>   ticket. This phenomenon is best illustrated using an example. Suppose
>   we are playing the PICK-4 Lotto and require one 2/4 win. Hence R=4,
>   J=2 and W=1. Furthermore let’s assume that the fortune-teller predicts
>   3 numbers from a set of 5 numbers ( i.e. P=3 and N=5 ). If all
>   P-subsets were taken from the fortune-teller set and arbitrarily
>   filled to complete the tickets, we would have a set of ten tickets
>   that guarantees one 2/4 win ( See Figure 1 ). However, it is also
>   possible to exclude some tickets from this set because of several
>   two-number overlaps. For instance the subset {3, 4, 5} is different
>   than {1, 3, 5} by only one number and it will be wasteful to use both
>   of these in purchased tickets. We might think that not including {3,
>   4, 5} will permit the possibility of losing, but that is not the case
>   since if {3, 4, 5}occurs we will have ‘3’ and ‘5’ in {1, 3, 5}that we
>   bought to claim the prize! Similarly there can be many more redundant
>   P-subsets. An optimal solution is shown in Figure 2. Our lottery
>   problem is that of finding the smallest set of P-subsets from the
>   fortune-teller set that guarantees the specified number of wins by
>   keeping the number of overlaps to a minimum. This set of P-subsets
>   defines the winning set regardless of what numbers are used to
>   complete the R slots on the ticket.

My question are followiong

1. As author metioned "If all P-subsets were taken from the fortune-teller set and arbitrarily filled to complete the tickets, we would have a set of ten tickets" As in article table is missing can any one help me here what are the 10 tickets?
2. In above example if 1 and 3 occurs and if we didn't select {1, 3, 5} how can we win here?
3. Can anyone come up with fig 2 which is missing in article?

thank!

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is an inefficent list of 10 tickets

   ```
   {1, 2, 3, 6}
   {1, 2, 4, 6}
   {1, 2, 5, 6}
   {1, 3, 4, 6}
   {1, 3, 5, 6}
   {1, 4, 5, 6}
   {2, 3, 4, 6}
   {2, 3, 5, 6}
   {2, 4, 5, 6}
   {3, 4, 5, 6}
   ```
2. Mu. To win we need to match 2 out of 4.  So it isn't the case that 1 and 3 occurs, it is the case that a specific set of 3 occurs and we only need to match 2 of them.
3. I think this is optimal.

   ```
   {1, 2, 3, 4}
   ```

But I'm not entirely positive that I can pick 4.  If I am only allowed to pick 3 per ticket then an optimal set would be:

```
    {1, 2, 3}
    {2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two tickets are:

{ 1, 3, 5, X }

{ 2, 4, 5, X }

where X is an arbitrarily chosen number which does not affect the solution.

Comment: Can you please explain how how it doesnot effect solution?

Comment: The fourth number does not matter. Because the tickets are bought as a set of four numbers there has to be a fourth number, but it does not matter what it is. The other numbers cover all winning possibilities.